# Cordova error building - EPERM, operation not permitted

Tags: android, svn, cordova

I am trying to build an android APK file for my project

```
C:\myApp>cordova build android
cp: copyFileSync: could not write to dest file (code=EPERM):C:\myApp\platforms\android\res\xml\config.xml

Error: EPERM, operation not permitted 'C:\myApp\platforms\android\res\xml\config.xml'
at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:438:18)
at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:977:15)
```

I used windows 7 64 Bit.
What could be the reason?

My files by the way are versioned by subversion and I am not sure if that is the case.

Anyone encountered this one?

Comment: EPERM means it does not have permission to perform the required operation. You need to either change the rights of the directory/file or login as admin and perform the operation.

Comment: Hi @frank, I tried running my command prompt as administrator already

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Re-install android as a platform, should re-create any folders that had bad permissions

`cordova platform remove android`

`cordova platform add android`

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem. This fixed the issue:

```
sudo chown -R yourUserName foldername
```

Answer (score 3):

Start Menu -> search "cmd" -> right click "cmd.exe" and "Run as administrator"

Fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility that has not been mentioned explicitly is that if your version control system marks files as read-only when you check them in, then this will cause EPERM errors during your build. You will have to work around this by having a pre-build event or hook (depending on your development environment) to remove this attribute from the files in question after they are copied to the platform specific location.

Answer (score 1):

Try closing your code editor(ex: VS code)

and run/build again.

I know this is a strange fix but this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The config.xml is generated by first copying the 'platforms\android\cordova\defaults.xml' file. If that file is read-only, then the config.xml will also be read-only and Cordova won't be able to modify it.

Either making both files writable, or checking them out from Source Control before building should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

"Error: EPERM" always means permission denied.
I resolved "Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open '\resources\android\icon\drawable-ldpi-icon.png'"
by removing read-only attribute for the required files shown in error.

There was 2 changes to avoid this error

1. **Removing Read-Only attribute** of the file mentioned in the error
2. Execute the **command prompt with admin privilege**

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything here, nothing worked to me. So here the solution for my case: **check antivirus (shields, etc.)**, that's was my problem, after turn it off, running the commands:

```
cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android
```

It worked ok.